# iframe height and width centering

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to have an iframe in a horizontally centered div. It works fine in Firefox but not in IE8. Here is my full code:

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML> -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head></head>
<STYLE type="text/css">
body {
background-color: silver; } 

#container {
align: right; 
margin: 0;
width: 600px;height: 100%;
margin: 10px auto;
background-color: white; 
}

#top {
height: 300px;
background-color: yellow; }

#midpart { 
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image:none;
background-color: blue; }

</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="top">
<iframe src="aa.htm" id="midpart" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1"></iframe>
</div>

</div>
</body></html>
```

In IE8 Above code produces a div which is not horizontally centered. Otherwise it is OK.
The iFrame div occupies about 100% of the screen as inteded. Please note that I am using the long doctype version

If I use the first doctype line (the short one) IE8 centers the div OK but div/iframe height is wrong.

Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to your body...

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Thanks! "text-align:center;" did it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have 'margin: 10px auto' and 'align:right' in #container?

Answer (score 0):

```
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
```

Should produce a horizontally centered div for the id of top.  You can set width and height directly on an iframe with the width and height attributes.